# Recylerview show only last added data and replace previously added data also;

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to show  data in recycler view but it only show last added data and not show previously added data
i tried for sqlite database but it didn't work so i tried first ststic data but it also show same error .
I try googling this but there no work on this problem.
i also try notifydatachanged() but it also not worked.
here is my adapter code:

```
public class fileAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<fileAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private final Context context;
private ArrayList<files> filelist;
private dbhelper mdb;
public fileAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<files> filelist){
    this.context=context;
    this.filelist=filelist;
    mdb=new dbhelper(context);

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_file, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(fileAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    final files file=filelist.get(i);
    viewHolder.name.setText(file.getFname());
    viewHolder.time.setText(file.getTime());

    ViewHolder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"click on item: "+files.getFname(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filelist.size();
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView name,time;
    public static RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        name=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        time=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.time);
        relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.listraw);
    }
}
```

}

this is  my activity

```
 private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private dbhelper db;
private ArrayList<files> allfiles=new ArrayList<>();
private fileAdapter madapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity2);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rec1);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    madapter = new fileAdapter(this,allfiles);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);

    newdata();





}

private void newdata() {
    files file=new files("1","e");
    allfiles.add(file);

     file=new files("2","4");
    allfiles.add(file);
    file=new files("3","5");
    allfiles.add(file);

    file=new files("4","6");
    allfiles.add(file);

    file=new files("5","7");
    allfiles.add(file);
    madapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

whenever i fetch the data in recylcer view it only show last added data.

activiy.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".activity2">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rec1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    />
```

list_raw.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listraw"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

             />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

for more code check here: https://github.com/AnkitsinhBa2p/test

Comment: Post your complete `list_raw.xml` file.

Comment: posted hope it work or check here: https://github.com/AnkitsinhBa2p/test

Comment: I have copied your example and made one example and it worked fine so can you please let me what is the issue are you facing?

Comment: Please clarify your question properly. What is the meaning of show only last added data and replace previously added data also. You are adding data only once in onCreate.So, everytime you go to the activity it will be same data. What is your problem??

Comment: pratik click on button it show only last added data not all data store in

Comment: hi ron https://ibb.co/5WBmLQP check image my input is                   allfiles.add(new files("2","4"));
        allfiles.add(new files("3","5"));
        allfiles.add(new files("4","5"));
        allfiles.add(new files("5","6"));

Comment: you can count your `filelist` size in adapter `constructor`. like `filelist.size()`. if the size is equal to your expectation then you need to modify your `list_raw.xml`.

Comment: filelist all are perfect but it show https://ibb.co/5WBmLQP this type error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using static fields in model class. Due to this you get same data whenever you get item in adapter to set values. Change your model class to this and it should work.

```
public class files {
private int id;
private String fname;
private String time;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFname() { return fname; }
public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}
public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public files() {
}

public files(int id, String fname, String time) {
    this.id = id;
    this.fname = fname;
    this.time = time;
}

public files(String fname, String time) {
    this.fname = fname;
    this.time = time;
}
}
```

Comment: this error generated   non-static method setData(ArrayList<files>) cannot be referenced from a static context  and if setData() make static then notifyDatasetchanger() not apply to static context

Comment: my bad, check code again. I edited answer. You need to call setData on madapter in activity.

Comment: this  also not able to solve error i have uploaded all my code here:https://github.com/AnkitsinhBa2p/test u can check here

Comment: what error are you getting? Your implementation on github is different from what you poster here.

Comment: here i posted activity 2 i got error on displaying data in recyclerview https://ibb.co/5WBmLQP show output here

Comment: main goal of this app is fetch the name and time from sqlite in recycler view but same problem.

Comment: i check my db file in this all data perfectly store  but in recyclerview it show last added data

Comment: hello arslan in github code i want to show data from sqlite database but it show only last added data same as image if you solve then it very helpful.

Comment: I've changed adapter and model. Check it.

Comment: as your code error in dbhelper()  in insertData() getFname,getTime static not referenced also need create files() without i parameter in model

Comment: change these two lines. it is using static reference but you are adding name and time of file.         contentValues.put(COL_2, file.getFname());
        contentValues.put(COL_3, file.getTime());

Comment: i remove static but not help

Comment: change files to file in insertData()

Comment: worked  one more help need i want to sort using name

Comment: create separate query with ORDER BY name.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private dbhelper db; 
private ArrayList<files> allfiles=new ArrayList<>(); 
private fileAdapter madapter;

        @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity2);

            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rec1);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

            madapter = new fileAdapter(this,allfiles);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);

            newdata();





        }

        private void newdata() {
            files file=new files("1","e");
            allfiles.add(file);

             file=new files("2","4");
            allfiles.add(file);
            file=new files("3","5");
            allfiles.add(file);

            file=new files("4","6");
            allfiles.add(file);

            file=new files("5","7");
            allfiles.add(file);
            madapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }
}
```

in This File First, you pass blank ArrayList in Adapter and SetAdapter so, here not any record in ArrayList. After setAdapter, you add newData() Method to add five-item to ArrayList and notify the adapter, so you get five items in the list. So, what's an issue? please, describe more...

Comment: in recyclerview it show  only last added data  it show 5 raw but all data are 5,7

Comment: Please, try to Replace newdata() with This,


`private void newdata() {
 allfiles.add(new files("1","e"))
 allfiles.add(new files("2","4"))
 allfiles.add(new files("3","5"))
 allfiles.add(new files("4","6"))
 allfiles.add(new files("5","7"))
        madapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to call the

> notifyItemRangeInserted

instead of the

> notifyDataSetChanged

Example:

```
private void newdata() {
    int currentSize = madapter.getItemCount();
    allfiles.add(new files("1","e"));
    allfiles.add(new files("2","4"));
    allfiles.add(new files("3","5"));
    allfiles.add(new files("4","6"));
    allfiles.add(new files("5","7"));
    madapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(currentSize , allfiles.size() - currentSize);
}
```

Comment: try this but problem still there

Answer (score 0):

Just made little changes in your code which are as follows:
First go into your activity_activity2.xml file and add this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rec1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".activity2" />
```

Just keep the code clean and simple
Then go into its corresponding logical file, which is named as activity2.java and this ->

```
package com.example.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private dbhelper db;
    private ArrayList<files> allfiles = new ArrayList<>();
    private fileAdapter madapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity2);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rec1);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        db = new dbhelper(this);
        allfiles.addAll(db.getAllData());
        madapter = new fileAdapter(this, allfiles);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);
        madapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I made changes in the LinearLayoutManger's function and added a single Loc at the end of code to refresh the data i.e. notifyDataSetChanged().

Now go into the row_file.xml file and added this ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Time"
            android:padding="8dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The main issue was over here. You have provided weight_sum attribute to the cardview and given weight to both the textview. i dont know in which orientation you wanted to create the layout. i just removed it and made it "vertical". But if you want then you can do the weight_sum by providing this to the "linear layout" view group which i have added into the cardview.

**Note:** *If you want to render more than one views in any of the orientation then you need to add a viewgroup inside the cardview.*

And here comes the part which is "fileAdapter" class. Just add these changes into your code ->

```
package com.example.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class fileAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<fileAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final Context context;
    private ArrayList<files> filelist;
    private dbhelper mdb;

    public fileAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<files> filelist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.filelist = filelist;
        mdb = new dbhelper(context);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                        .inflate(
                                R.layout.row_file,
                                viewGroup,
                                false
                        )
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull fileAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.name.setText(files.getFname());
        viewHolder.time.setText(files.getTime());

        viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "click on item: " + files.getFname(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filelist.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name, time;
        CardView cardView;

        private ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            cardView = v.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
            name = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            time = v.findViewById(R.id.time);
        }
    }
}
```

I have removed the "relative layout" from here as it was not required and made the cardview the parent container and binded it into the "ViewHolder" innner class of the "fileAdapter" class file. Thats all.

I have tested the code at my side and its working fine. If there is any issue at yours just let me know. Thank you.

Comment: i check and tell you.

Comment: https://ibb.co/VNr7Z2g see this all data are same this is problem and the data store in db is different see in this  image https://ibb.co/qDqFN2M

Comment: Ok I understand what you wanna say. Just wait for some time. I'll resolve it.

Comment: I have uploaded the changes here. Just check it. I m getting the result as you wanted and shown me into the picture. Its working fine. Let me know if there is still any issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So the changes are as such
In your activity2.java file add this ->

```
package com.example.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private dbhelper db;
    private ArrayList<files> allfiles;
    private fileAdapter madapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity2);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rec1);
        allfiles = new ArrayList<>();
        db = new dbhelper(this);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        allfiles.addAll(db.getAllData());
        madapter = new fileAdapter(this, allfiles);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);
        madapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Then in your "file.java" modal class ->

```
package com.example.test;


public class files {
    private int id;
    private String fname;
    private String time;

    public files(String fname, String time) {
        this.fname = fname;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

Create only one constructor which will be used in your db for getting the data.

Now in your "dbhelper.java" class add this ->

```
public ArrayList<files> getAllData() {

        ArrayList<files> filesList = new ArrayList<>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            filesList.clear();   //Added this line to clear the arraylist before fetching and adding the whole data again. It will make the list duplicate free.
            do {
                filesList.add(new files(
                        cursor.getString(1),
                        cursor.getString(2)
                ));     // Fetched the data by using the modal class constructor

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();

        return filesList;
    }
```

The main issue was in the dbhelper's getAllData() function. I modified it by clearing the list at first and then fetched the data by using the constructor of the modal class and correspondingly added that data into the arraylist of the db.

Then lastly into the "fileAdapter.java" class make these following changes to fetch the data properly from the modal class

```
public fileAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<files> filelist) {
    this.context = context;
    this.filelist = filelist;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull fileAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    final files mFile = filelist.get(i);

    viewHolder.name.setText(mFile.getFname());
    viewHolder.time.setText(mFile.getTime());

    viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "click on item: " + mFile.getFname(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

And finally it works properly.